# Replacing string between two characters in the file

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a string in my proprieties file as below:

```
line = "variables=ORACLE_BASE_HOME=/u02/test/oracle/landscape/1/db_50,DB_UNIQUE_NAME=cdms,ORACLE_BASE=//u02/test,PDB_NAME=,DB_NAME=cdms,ORACLE_HOME=/u02/test/product/19/db_21,SID=ss"
```

I would like to replace the following string with a different value:

```
DB_NAME=cdms -> DB_NAME=abc
```

I have the code below, however, it seems not doing as expected:

```
f = fileinput.FileInput(rsp_file_path)
for line in f:
    re.sub(",DB_NAME=(.*?),", "abc", line, flags=re.DOTALL)
f.close()
```

Comment: "it seems not doing as expected": Please explain what this means.

Comment: Hi @Scott Hunter, the file/value did not get updated. Old value still preserved

Comment: Did you read the documentation on `re.sub` to see what it does, and more importantly, what it returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
re.sub("(,DB_NAME=)(.*?),", "\g<1>abc,", line, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

or using raw string:

```
re.sub(r"(,DB_NAME=)(.*?),", r"\1abc,", line, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

That's because the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) for `re.sub()` states:

> In string-type repl arguments, in addition to the character escapes
>   and backreferences described above, \g will use the substring
>   matched by the group named name, as defined by the (?P...)
>   syntax. \g uses the corresponding group number; \g<2> is
>   therefore equivalent to \2, but isn’t ambiguous in a replacement such
>   as \g<2>0. \20 would be interpreted as a reference to group 20, not a
>   reference to group 2 followed by the literal character '0'. The
>   backreference \g<0> substitutes in the entire substring matched by the
>   RE.

In your case `(,DB_NAME=)` is the first captured group which you refer to with `\g<1>`.

Comment: Does this not still suffer from "the file/value did not get updated. Old value still preserved "?

Comment: @jignatius. Thanks for pointing that out, should check that closely.

Answer (score -1):

you can use use string.replace()

```
s.replace('DB_NAME', 'cdms', 1).replace('DB_NAME', 'abc', 1)
```

Comment: As the regex in the question clearly indicates, the desire is to replace *whatever* value is assigned to `DB_NAME`.